# Typescript (Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type) Why is my Array having a | undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array called `combinedMarkets` which is either a combination of 5 or 3 different market arrays. All these arrays have the following interface `IMarketAsset[]`:

```
export interface IMarketAsset {
  exchange: string;
  base: string;
  quote: string;
  price_quote: string;
  timestamp: string;
}
```

Here is where the typescript error occurs:

```
const combinedMarkets = asset !== 'BTC' && asset !== 'ETH' ?
  btcMarkets.concat(ethMarkets).concat(marketUSD).concat(marketUSDC).concat(marketUSDT) :
  marketUSD.concat(marketUSDC).concat(marketUSDT);

const filteredMarkets = combinedMarkets.length > 0 ? filterByUSDbase(asset, combinedMarkets) : [];
```

> Argument of type '({ price_quote: string; exchange: string; base: string; quote: string; timestamp: string; } | undefined)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IMarketAsset[]'.
>     Type '{ price_quote: string; exchange: string; base: string; quote: string; timestamp: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IMarketAsset'.
>       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IMarketAsset'.ts(2345)
>
> ```
> const combinedMarkets: ({
>   price_quote: string;
>   exchange: string;
>   base: string;
>   quote: string;
>   timestamp: string;
> } | undefined)[]
> ```

[image]

**Why is combinedMarkets an array of either an object of type `IMarketAsset` or undefined?**

### Full combineExchangeData Function

```
// Filter by BTC, ETH, USD, USDT or USDC prices
// If asset has BTC/ETH pairing, obtain exchange BTC/ETH price to calculate assets USD/USDT value
export const combineExchangeData =
  (asset: string, { marketBTC, marketETH, marketUSD, marketUSDT, marketUSDC }: IGetMarketsRes) => {
    const btcBasedExchanges = marketBTC.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === asset);
    const ethBasedExchanges = marketETH.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === asset);
    const btcUSDTprices = marketUSDT.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === 'BTC');
    const btcUSDprices = marketUSD.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === 'BTC');
    const ethUSDTprices = marketUSDT.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === 'ETH');
    const ethUSDprices = marketUSD.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === 'ETH');

    const btcPricedMarkets = filterByExchangeBase(btcBasedExchanges, btcUSDTprices, btcUSDprices);
    const ethPricedMarkets = filterByExchangeBase(ethBasedExchanges, ethUSDTprices, ethUSDprices);

    const btcMarkets = btcPricedMarkets.filter((market) => R.not(R.isNil(market)));
    const ethMarkets = ethPricedMarkets.filter((market) => R.not(R.isNil(market)));

    const combinedMarkets = asset !== 'BTC' && asset !== 'ETH' ?
      btcMarkets.concat(ethMarkets).concat(marketUSD).concat(marketUSDC).concat(marketUSDT) :
      marketUSD.concat(marketUSDC).concat(marketUSDT);

    console.log('combinedMarkets', combinedMarkets);
    const filteredMarkets = combinedMarkets.length > 0 ? filterByUSDbase(asset, combinedMarkets) : [];
    console.log('filteredMarkets', filteredMarkets);

    if (R.isEmpty(filteredMarkets)) return [];

    return filteredMarkets.map((market: IMarketAsset) => {
      if (market) {
        return {
          ...market,
          price_quote: formatPrice(market.price_quote)
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

### Util functions

Here are the 2 other util functions I use in the main function. Also I have narrowed down the problem to the `btcMarkets` and `ethMarkets` arrays. So looking at `filterByExchangeBase`.

```
import * as R from 'ramda'

import { USD_CURRENCIES } from '../shared/constants/api'
import { IMarketAsset } from '../shared/types'

const calculateBasePrice = (assetBtcPrice: string | number, btcPrice: string | number) => 
  (Number(assetBtcPrice) * Number(btcPrice)).toString();

export const filterByExchangeBase =
  (exchanges: IMarketAsset[], usdtExchanges: IMarketAsset[], usdExchanges: IMarketAsset[]) =>
    exchanges.map((exchange) => {
      let basePriced = usdtExchanges.filter((btcExchange) => btcExchange.exchange === exchange.exchange)[0];

      if (!basePriced) {
        basePriced = usdExchanges.filter((btcExchange) => btcExchange.exchange === exchange.exchange)[0];
      }

      if (basePriced) {
        const { price_quote: assetBtcPrice } = exchange;
        const { price_quote: btcPrice } = basePriced;

        return {
          ...exchange,
          price_quote: calculateBasePrice(assetBtcPrice, btcPrice)
        }
      }
    });

export const filterByUSDbase = (asset: string, combinedMarkets: IMarketAsset[] | undefined) => {
  if (!combinedMarkets) return [];
  return R.not(R.any(R.equals(asset))(USD_CURRENCIES))
    ? combinedMarkets.filter((marketAsset: IMarketAsset) => {
      if (marketAsset && marketAsset.base) {
        return marketAsset.base === asset;
      }
    }) : [];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my `filterByExchangeBase` util function, I used `.map` instead of `.filter` which would result in some `undefined` objects in that array. Switching to filter made sure that only existing items would make it into the array.

...

### Update: By changing .map to .filter, the price_quote updates didn't take

Refactored the logic to make sure that btcMarkets and ethMarkets aren't used if they will be empty.

```
export const combineExchangeData =
  (asset: string, { marketBTC, marketETH, marketUSD, marketUSDT, marketUSDC }: IGetMarketsRes) => {
    const btcBasedExchanges = marketBTC.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === asset);
    const ethBasedExchanges = marketETH.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === asset);
    const btcUSDTprices = marketUSDT.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === 'BTC');
    const btcUSDprices = marketUSD.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === 'BTC');
    const ethUSDTprices = marketUSDT.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === 'ETH');
    const ethUSDprices = marketUSD.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => market.base === 'ETH');

    const btcPricedMarkets = notBTCorETH(asset) ? filterCryptoBase(btcBasedExchanges, btcUSDTprices, btcUSDprices) : [];
    const ethPricedMarkets = notBTCorETH(asset) ? filterCryptoBase(ethBasedExchanges, ethUSDTprices, ethUSDprices) : [];

    const btcMarkets = R.not(R.isEmpty(btcPricedMarkets)) ? btcPricedMarkets.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => R.not(R.isNil(market))) : [];
    const ethMarkets = R.not(R.isEmpty(ethPricedMarkets)) ? ethPricedMarkets.filter((market: IMarketAsset) => R.not(R.isNil(market))) : [];

    const combinedMarkets = notBTCorETH(asset) ?
      btcMarkets.concat(ethMarkets).concat(marketUSD).concat(marketUSDC).concat(marketUSDT) :
      marketUSD.concat(marketUSDC).concat(marketUSDT);

    const filteredMarkets = filterByUSDbase(asset, combinedMarkets);

    if (R.isEmpty(filteredMarkets)) return [];

    return filteredMarkets.map((market: IMarketAsset) => ({
      ...market,
      price_quote: formatPrice(market.price_quote)
    }));
  };
```

---

```
export const filterCryptoBase =
  (exchanges: IMarketAsset[] | any, usdtExchanges: IMarketAsset[], usdExchanges: IMarketAsset[]) => {
    return exchanges.map((exchange: IMarketAsset) => {
      let basePriced = usdtExchanges.filter((btcExchange) => btcExchange.exchange === exchange.exchange)[0];
      if (!basePriced) {
        basePriced = usdExchanges.filter((btcExchange) => btcExchange.exchange === exchange.exchange)[0];
      }

      if (exchange && basePriced && exchange.price_quote && basePriced.price_quote) {
        const { price_quote: assetBtcPrice } = exchange; // Asset price in BTC/ETH
        const { price_quote: usdPrice } = basePriced; // BTC/ETH price in USDT/USD
        const price_quote = calculateBasePrice(assetBtcPrice, usdPrice).toString();

        return {
          ...exchange,
          price_quote
        }
      }

      return null;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is combinedMarkets an array either and object of type IMarketAsset or undefined

Because any of the `marketXXX` arrays, is an array of `IMarketAsset | undefined` (instead of just `IMarketAsset`.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to figure out why that is, I think I've narrowed it down to `combinedMarkets` sometimes containing empty arrays during the `concat` part of the logic, so will try filtering out empty arrays.

Comment: Ok my fix doesn't really fix the problem. I have to use `export const filterCryptoBase =
  (exchanges: IMarketAsset[] | any` to avoid a typescript error. Will offer this for bounty tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the type as an array for each option, instead of combining them:

```js
const combinedMarkets: {
    price_quote: string;
    exchange: string;
    base: string;
    quote: string;
    timestamp: string;
}[] | undefined[] = [];
```

Comment: ? but each array is of the same type `IMarketAsset` so when I concated all of them, they are still of type `IMarketAsset`

Comment: Could you post an example of this `type` You are correct in that I need a type that supports both `IMarketAsset` and undefined in an array.